# Converting a column of numbers to a date time

Tags: r, date, datetime, anytime

I'm trying to convert a table column (aifstime_local) containing dates which are currently stored as numbers into datetime. see below for table.

```r
    aifstime_utc aifstime_local      lat      lon apparent_t cloud cloud_base_m
1 20190224230000 20190225083000 -12.6099 131.0474       31.8     -         NULL
2 20190224223000 20190225080000 -12.6099 131.0474       30.9     -         NULL
3 20190224220000 20190225073000 -12.6099 131.0474       30.1     -         NULL
4 20190224213000 20190225070000 -12.6099 131.0474       30.2     -         NULL
5 20190224210000 20190225063000 -12.6099 131.0474       30.2     -         NULL
6 20190224203000 20190225060000 -12.6099 131.0474       29.4     -         NULL
```

I've tried using the anytime function from the anytime package

```r
library(anytime)
MyData$aifstime_local <- anytime(MyData$aifstime_local)
```

However this only returns the date, and not the datetime as I need, See below

```r
 aifstime_utc aifstime_local      lat      lon apparent_t cloud cloud_base_m
1 20190224230000     2019-02-25 -12.6099 131.0474       31.8     -         NULL
2 20190224223000     2019-02-25 -12.6099 131.0474       30.9     -         NULL
3 20190224220000     2019-02-25 -12.6099 131.0474       30.1     -         NULL
4 20190224213000     2019-02-25 -12.6099 131.0474       30.2     -         NULL
5 20190224210000     2019-02-25 -12.6099 131.0474       30.2     -         NULL
6 20190224203000     2019-02-25 -12.6099 131.0474       29.4     -         NULL
```

Are there any functions that can help with this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lubridate`'s `ymd_hms` :

```
lubridate::ymd_hms(df$aifstime_utc)
```

OR in base R use `as.POSIXct` specifying appropriate format based on the data.

```
as.POSIXct(as.character(df$aifstime_utc), format = '%Y%m%d%H%M%S', tz = 'UTC')
```

Note that both of these give time in `UTC` timezone, if you want it in your local timezone use correct `tz` argument in  `ymd_hms` and remove `tz = 'UTC` in `as.POSIXct`.